# “An item with the same key has already been added” in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, synchronization

I am trying to add some elements to a dictionary in C# but I've been running into some problems. I am new to C# development so I hope someone could help me with this.

The code for adding the element is:

```
if (!connections.ContainsKey(port.getParentName()))
{
    connections.Add(port.getParentName(), port.getLabel() + ";" + cable + ";" + cableTemplate + "|");
}
else
{
    connections[port.getParentName()] += port.getLabel() + ";" + cable + ";" + cableTemplate + "|";
}
```

Although I'm checking if the key is allready contained in my ports dictionary I'm getting:

```
“An item with the same key has already been added”
```

Have to mention also that I am getting the data asynchronously so I would guess that this is a synchronization issue. I tried to handle this by locking this block of code but this does not seem to solve the problem:

```
System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();
lock (lockThis)
{
    ....
}
```

Also have to mention that I am not getting this error all the time. Just that occasionally when starting the application. Any idea what could be causing this? Is the way I'm making the synchronization wrong or is it something else?

Answer (score 6):

1. Your lock is invalid. You need to have *one* instance to lock on. You currently create a new one everytime.
2. Use a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead and use [`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378664.aspx). This removes the need for a lock altogether:

   ```
   var value = port.getLabel() + ";" + cable + ";" + cableTemplate + "|";
   connections.AddOrUpdate(port.getParentName(), value, (k, v) => v + value);
   ```

Comment: @ShellShock: I know. You comment an old version of my answer.

Comment: More nitpicking: the lockObject should have the same scope & lifetime as the Dictionary.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answers. What would be a correct way of locking? I need this for other parts of the code also? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Move your synchronization object in the scope of the class:

```
public class Test
{    
    private object syncRoot = new object();

    private void Foo()
    {
        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Make it static or not, depending on how you use your class.

Comment: Thank you all! We were all of great help!

Answer (score 2):

[ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) can handle the synchronization issues for you.

Comment: I'm not sure this is strictly a correct answer. I came here as I'm already using the `ConcurrentDictionary` but still getting "the key already existed" errors - evidently because I need a lock to prevent another thread from adding the offending item, before I run the next line of code. So the `ConcurrentDictionary` is "coping" but definitely handling this issue by itself